# Redux action dispatch

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-actions

In my redux action, I have one action will be called by another two actions, code is below:

```
export const addParticipantFromPopupRequest = (participant, project_id, currentStep) => async (dispatch) => {
    const result = await addParticipant(participant)
    dispatch({ type: PARTICIPANT_ADD, payload: result })
    dispatch(updateProjectStep(project_id, currentStep))
}
```

```
export const handleFinalStep = (projectId, currentStep) => async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(updateProjectStep(projectId, currentStep))
}
```

```
const updateProjectStep = (projectId, currentStep) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch({ type: MODAL_STATUS_CHANGE, payload: { projectId, currentStep } })
    dispatch({ type: PROJECT_PROCESS_LIST_UPDATE, payload: { project_id: projectId, currentStep } })
    const { projectsProcessListsReducer } = getState()
    localStorage.setItem("projectsProcessLists", JSON.stringify(projectsProcessListsReducer))
}
```

If I dont' use dispatch when call updateProjectStep, the addParticipantFromPopupRequest and handleFinalStep cannot run correct.

My question is can I call dispatch actions in this way and is it correct? Why I need the "dispatch" when I call updateProjectStep in another actions rather than call function name directly?

Comment: Yes, actions can dispatch other actions and must use the `dispatch()` method to do so. Simple action functions do nothing more than return an object, which must be dispatched to redux to do anything. Here you are technically writing "thunk" actions, which return a function instead of an object.

Answer (score 1):

**My question is can I call dispatch actions in this way and is it correct?**

Yes. You should always call with the `dispatch`.

**Why I need the "dispatch" when I call updateProjectStep in another actions rather than call function name directly?**

If you call `updateProjectStep` directly without `dispatch`, it will become a normal js function call and your `store` won't be aware of it. Dispatch is the only way to trigger a state change in `store`.

> In `redux` the `store` is **single source of truth**, the `dispatch` you are using is actually comes from `store` (`store.dispatch`).

> If you call a function normally then it won't be aware by the `store`. That action won't pass through the `middlewares` (thunk/saga) that `store` is aware of and won't do the `store` update via `reducers`.

> If `store` is not updated, your components won't receive any updates. **Eventually your UI won't re-render.**

You can find more about dispatch [here](https://redux.js.org/api/store#dispatchaction).